# WatiN handler for vbscript Input Box

Tags: testing, automation, watin

Do anyone have a solution for handling a vbscript inputbox with watin, and to be clear this is not the same a javascripts prompt or vbscript msgbox or etc....

I have and used handlers for those but cannot find a way to handle the input box and i do not have the pull to get the developers to change the code to use prompt and javascript like they have in some many other places in our old vb6 systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom dialog handler that can handle the window. The trick to doing that is to get spy++ and match the right window style. Another method might be to call the document.eval method and close it using javascript.

Comment: thx dude, i found a work around but im sure this will rear its ugly head sometime in the future.